# Modify Behavior Subject stream dynamically

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I got a situation where I'd like to dynamically add a property to some object in `BehaviorSubject<any[]>`. I got component A and B, where A is subscribed to observable from service. I need to be able to somehow manipulate that stream from component B where I would attach some prop to an index item of that array in BehaviorSubject.

Component A:

.html

```
<pre>{{ data$ | async | json }}</pre>
```

.ts

```
export class DummyComponent implements OnInit {
  data$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private dummyService: DummyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data$ = this.dummyService.someData$;
  }
}
```

Component B:

.html

```
<button (click)="foo()">Click</button>
```

.ts

```
export class Dummy2Component {

  constructor(private dummyService: DummyService) { }

  foo() {
    this.dummyService.someAction(0, () => {
      console.log('test');
    });
  }
}
```

Service with data (Dummy Service):

```
export const someRandomData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: 'foo'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'bar'
  }
]

@Injectable()
export class DummyService {
  private someDataSource$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(someRandomData);
  someData$: Observable<any> = this.someDataSource$.asObservable();

  someAction(index: number, fn: () => void): void {
    this.someData$ = this.someData$.pipe(
      map(items => {
        console.log(items);
        items[index].onClick = fn;
        return items;
      })
    )
  }
}
```

In Component B I got the button that calls `foo()` function and that function gets executed, but when it calls someAction() in DummyService, it doesn't modify stream. That stream stays unchanged. It never console.logs(item) even tho someData$ is subscribed in Component A.

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Here's stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zyr5r6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't replace stream with another stream but rather dispatch a new value:

```
someAction(index: number, fn: () => void): void {
  const items = this.someDataSource$.value;
  items[index].onClick = 'fn';
  this.someDataSource$.next([...items]);
}
```

Another issue here is that you won't see any UI changes because you use json pipe. And  functions are not visible to any serializer.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ussd57?file=src/app/dummy.service.ts)**

Comment: i thought more of pipe aproach as i already subscribed to that Observable... but this should do the job too. Thanks! :)